# How to create MVC project in visual studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2017

Already I have visual studio 2015, recently I installed visual studio 2017. I have the.NETCore 2+ SDK installed. But when I want to create the new project, I am not able to create MVC project. Please guide me.

Comment: You probably may be missing templates. You can install them along with all other modules using Windows 'Uninstall' or 'Change' tool in Windows Control Panel->Programs. (You should be able to reinstall your Visual Studio with additional modules)

Comment: @Paradowski thanks for your guide. I reinstall Visual Studio, after that, I have ASP.NET Core Web Application but There is not MVC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: make sure you installed the web development workload.

**Steps to follow**

1. Search and launch *Visual Studio Installer*
2. Click on *Modify*
3. Choose **ASP.NET and web development** [image: Choose the ASP.NET and web development workload]
4. Make sure that the option **.NET Framework 4 – 4.6 development tools** is checked on the right side, under *ASP.NET and web development*
5. Click on *Modify* to install the workload

---

After relaunching VS2017, choose ASP.NET Core Web Application:

[image: Choose ASP.NET Core Web Application]

Hopefully this solves your problem :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. my problem solved a little. because I see ASP.NET Core Web Application in my visual, but I do not see MVC. @Matthijs

Comment: You should see a new window when you choose *ASP.NET Core Web Application*. There will be multiple options available, like MVC.

Comment: Yes, I see new window after  ASP.NET Core Web Application. But there is not MVC. I really don't know the reason.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli Now, select Web Application and click OK. In this template, we cannot find ASP.NET MVC template because MVC 6 or ASP.NET Core is a default MVC (Model-View-Controller) structure. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37549.asp-net-mvc-6-in-visual-studio-2017-basics.aspx